# SSIS - Error Output - Redirect row

Tags: sql-server, redirect, ssis, dataflow

I've got a question about the result I'm getting with the execution of a task in SSIS.

First of all, this query is been executing from Access. The original source is a set of table in Oracle and the Destination is a local table in Access. This table has a composite primary key. When I execute the query from access as a result I'm getting over one million registers, but before insert this result in the table, Access is showing me a message where it informs that 26 registers violate the primary key constraint (they are repeated). So they are not taken into account.

I have created the destination table in SQL SERVER with the same primary key, I am using the same source used in Access (the same query), but when the data flow begins to work, immediately more than 200.000 register are being redirecting as a error output. And, of course, I was waiting the same result seen in Access, only 26 registers taken as an error.

These are the message from Access:

[image]

This is my configuration for SSIS, and its result:

[image]

Result

[image]

I tried to explain this doubt as clear as possible, but English is not my mother tongue.

If you need clarify something about , please ask me.

Regards.

Comment: All of the 200k errors are on pk violations ?

Comment: Hi Amir, only 32 are in pk violations. I have updated the table, by deleting the primary key, then I have done a group by just to see how many of them are repeted and the answer is 32. That is why I am very lost with my results.

Comment: Then what are the errors on the rest of the records ?   Column datatypes missmatch ?  FK violations ?  Is the data inserted in batches or every row on it's own ? The last could cause an entire batch of records to fail due to a single row.  If removing the PK allowed to insert all the records with no problems, then this could be the case.  If you know the 32 pk-values, try filtering them out in a where clause, and see if the rest are processed.  If they all succeed that could be the case.

Comment: Hi @Amir. I have put some images, may be it would be easier to see any possible problem. Thans for any help you can give me.

Comment: Can you post the error logs ? not just the print screen of the "process flow" page ?  And did you verify that the destination data types match the input ?

Comment: It's not having an error. As you can see, I'am no having the same result that I've got from Access, instead of 26 rows no taken into account, I'm having 673.200. Wich I did not expect.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make the assumption that you're using the default configuration for the `OLEDB Destination`. This means that the **Rows per batch** is empty (-1) and a **Maximum insert commit size** of 2147483647.

**Rows per batch**

> Specify the number of rows in a batch. The default value of this
>   property is –1, which indicates that no value has been assigned.

**Maximum insert commit size**

> Specify the batch size that the OLE DB destination tries to commit
>   during fast load operations. The value of 0 indicates that all data is
>   committed in a single batch after all rows have been processed.

If the rows are offered to the `OLEDB Destination` in batches of 200.000 all those rows will be inserted in one batch/transaction. If the batch contains one error then the whole batch will fail.

Changes to Rows per batch to 1 will solve this problem but will have a performance impact since it has to insert each row separately.

Comment: Hi @JodyT . I have put some images, may be it would be easier to see any possible problem. Thans for any help you can give me. Until now, anything seems to work.